# Doctrine2 - Unidirectional ManyToOne

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I am using Zend-Framework 2 with Doctrine 2.

In the application i am developing, i got 2 entities under different namespace:

- System\User\Entity\User
- Application\Apps\Timesheet\Entity\Worklog

In `Application\Apps\Timesheet\Entity\Worklog`, Every worklog has a user, since the entities reside in different module under different namespace, I want to store a uni-directional user relation in Worklog entity.

Currently I am using the following structure to store the relation between Worklog and a user.

```
class Worklog
{
     /**
     * Worklog Identifier.
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * User who logged the work
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Apps\Timesheet\Entity\User",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="timesheet_worklog_user",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="worklog_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @var object
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

Although, this work, Issue with this approach is, It stores the relation in a different table, I am wondering If it is possible to store user relation in the same `worklog` table with a column `user_id`, can someone give me some pointer in here?

Here is the code I am using:

```
namespace System\User\Entity;
/**
 * User class.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="system_user")
 */
class User
{
     /**
     * User Identifier
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Full name of the user.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, length=255)
     * @var string
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * User email.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, length=255)
     * @var string
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $email;
}

namespace Application\Apps\Timesheet\Entity;
/**
 * User Worklog.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="timesheet_worklog")
 */
class Worklog
{
     /**
     * Worklog Identifier.
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * Start Time
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", nullable=false, type="datetime")
     * @var DateTime Object
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $startTime;

    /**
     * End time.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", nullable=false, type="datetime")
     * @var DateTime Object
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $endTime;

    /**
     * User who logged the work
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Apps\Timesheet\Entity\User",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="timesheet_worklog_user",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="worklog_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @var object
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a ManyToMany relation instead of a ManyToOne?  ManyToMany is what is causing the join table to be generated.

Comment: This is indeed quite strange, but this is how doctrine recommend to do it, check out this link http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

Comment: @Cerad, you pointed me to the right direction, It works, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the similar issue, i solved this by changing

```
/**
 * User who logged the work
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Apps\Timesheet\Entity\User",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="timesheet_worklog_user",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="worklog_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @var object
 * @access protected
 */
protected $user;
```

To

```
/**
 * User who logged the work
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="System\User\Entity\User",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @var object
 * @access protected
 */
protected $user;
```

Thank you @Cerad for pointing to right direction.